# Change a background image onclick?

Tags: onclick

I'm extremely confused and I've been trying to do this for a while. This is just for a simple tumblr theme. I'm trying to make it so viewers can click a link and when it's clicked, the background image of the page switches. 
This is the page, eiramanaik.tumblr.com
The background image is shown, and when clicked, I want it to change to this: http://i50.tinypic.com/23lz49h.jpg

I've looked through everything, and even if I understood the coding, I didn't understand how to apply it, as I am very new to html in general.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use jquery is: (first you have to put id into your link as id="link")

```
<script type="text/javascript"
 src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
$('#link').click(function(){
$('#id_background').attr('src','23lz49h.jpg');
});
});

</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by putting my id into link?

Comment: in jquery you need to refer the html elements by using id as you can see in the code above. so you need something like that <div id="link">click here</div> so when someone click here jquery execute this peace of code $('#link').click(function(){ ....... }); Similarly you have to put id into your background image as <img src="id_background"/> in order to change the image

Comment: I'm still very confused. So far I have this. www.eiramanaik.tumblr.com So, there's something I'm not understanding or applying.

Comment: <a href="http://i50.tinypic.com/23lz49h.jpg">Click this</a> change this for <div id='link'>Click this<div> and which image do you want to change?

Comment: try this: $('body').css('background-image', 'url(http://static.tumblr.com/iio0iat/6Qwm63ml1/patterns1.jpg)'); inside .click(function(){  here });

Comment: Such as this? <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"
 src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
$('http://i50.tinypic.com/23lz49h.jpg').click(function(){$('body').css('background-image', 'url(static.tumblr.com/iio0iat/6Qwm63ml1/patterns1.jpg)';);});
$('http://i50.tinypic.com/23lz49h.jpg').attr('src','23lz49h.jpg');
});
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<p><div id='http://i50.tinypic.com/23lz49h.jpg'>Click this<div></p>

Comment: better if the id is just a name not a url. type id="button" o something like that don't put 'i50.tinypic...'